# Enhancing very thin lines in images

Tags: image-processing, edge-detection, enhancement

I want to detect filopodia (red arrow indicates filopodia in a vessel image).

[image]

My strategy is that if $I$ is the original and $J$ is the another image after opening operation. Then, $I-J$ is the filopodia. (See [Figure 6 in this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/251567685_FiloDetect_Automatic_detection_of_filopodia_from_fluorescence_microscopy_images)).

To do this, I want to enhance the very thin lines. How to do it? I also have information of front line like this:

[image]

Or, do you have any idea for detecting filopodia?

Comment: define "very smalll widths" in pixels; if they are in the order of single pixels, you will have a hard time based on frequency content alone.

Comment: sorry for ambiguity. It means "very thin".

Comment: what's "very thin" in pixels? (the wording is totally OK, just: numbers are better than words like "small" or "thin")

Comment: there is no exact definition for that, because the terminology is from the context of biology. Red arrows indicate filopodia which I want to segment.

Comment: the point is that this is a DSP problem, so a bit of info on how the problem behaves digitally is necessary.